# Returning a string to a variable length character array

Tags: c

I have a program that reverses a string from an input of a variable length character array. The function returns a variable length character array and is printed. When I print the output, I do get the reversed string, but there are garbage characters appended to it in my console print.

Is this a "legal" operation in terms of returning to buffers? Can someone please critique my code and suggest a better alternative if it is not the right approach?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *reverse_string(char *input_string);

char *reverse_string(char *input_string)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *return_string;
    char filled_buffer[16];
    while (input_string[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    while (i!=0)
    {
        filled_buffer[j]=input_string[i-1];
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    return_string=filled_buffer;
    printf("%s", return_string);
    return return_string;
}

int main (void) 
{
    char *returned_string;
    returned_string=reverse_string("tasdflkj");
    printf("%s", returned_string);
    return  1;
}
```

This is my output from Xcode - jklfdsat\347\322̲\227\377\231\235

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't safe to return a pointer to a local string in a function.  C won't stop you doing it (though sometimes the compiler will warn you if you ask it to; in this case, the local variable `return_string` prevents it giving the warning unless you change the code to `return filled_buffer;`).  But it is not safe. Basically, the space gets reused by other functions, and so they merrily trample on what was once a neatly formatted string.

> Can you explain this comment in more detail — "No, it isn't safe..."

The local variables (as opposed to string constants) go out of scope when the function returns.  Returning a pointer to an out-of-scope variable is *undefined behaviour*, which is something to be avoided at all costs.  When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen — including the program appearing to work — and there are no grounds for complaint, even if the program reformats your hard drive.  Further, it is not guaranteed that the same thing will happen on different machines, or even with different versions of the same compiler on your current machine.

Either pass the output buffer to the function, or have the function use `malloc()` to allocate memory which can be returned to and freed by the calling function.

#### Pass output buffer to function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int reverse_string(char *input_string, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz);

int reverse_string(char *input_string, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t i = strlen(input_string);
    if (i >= bufsiz)
        return -1;

    buffer[i] = '\0';
    while (i != 0)
    {
        buffer[j] = input_string[i-1];
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}

int main (void) 
{
    char buffer[16];
    if (reverse_string("tasdflkj", buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == 0)
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Memory allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_string(char *input_string);

char *reverse_string(char *input_string)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t i = strlen(input_string) + 1;
    char *string = malloc(i);
    if (string != 0)
    {
        string[--i] = '\0';
        while (i != 0)
        {
            string[j] = input_string[i-1];
            i--;
            j++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    return string;
}

int main (void) 
{
    char *buffer = reverse_string("tasdflkj");
    if (buffer != 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the sample code includes a newline at the end of each format string; it makes it easier to tell where the ends of the strings are.

This is an alternative `main()` which shows that the allocated memory returned is OK even after multiple calls to the `reverse_string()` function (which was modified to take a `const char *` instead of a plain `char *` argument, but was otherwise unchanged).

```
int main (void) 
{
    const char *strings[4] =
    {
        "tasdflkj",
        "amanaplanacanalpanama",
        "tajikistan",
        "ablewasiereisawelba",
    };
    char *reverse[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        reverse[i] = reverse_string(strings[i]);
        if (reverse[i] != 0)
            printf("[%s] reversed [%s]\n", strings[i], reverse[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Still valid: %s\n", reverse[i]);
        free(reverse[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also (as [pwny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600591/pwny) pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16578538/15168) before I added this note to mine), you need to make sure your string is null terminated.  It still isn't safe to return a pointer to the local string, even though you might not immediately spot the problem with your sample code.  This accounts for the garbage at the end of your output.

Comment: Can you explain this comment in more deatil - "No, it isn't safe to return a pointer to a local string in a function. "

Comment: So when you allocate memory, this is considered safe? Meaning - it does not go out of scope, it has still be been allocated?

Comment: What is the difference between allocating memory like this - char *return_string=malloc(sizeof *return_string);   vs    int * array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
My understanding is that the first approach is not safe as well, because the length is not defined

Comment: (1) When you allocate memory with `malloc()`, it stays allocated and accessible until you free it with `free()` or change its allocation with `realloc()` (though sometimes `realloc()` returns a pointer to the original space). (2) The `sizeof` operator normally evaluates its argument at compile time, not run time (the exception is when the argument is a VLA, variable length array). The first of your `malloc()` calls allocates 1 byte, which is insufficient for most strings (only the empty string fits), but within that constraint is 'safe'. The second `malloc()` is OK for an array of 10 `int`.

Comment: If I were to allocate memory using the first call, then assign it a string with more bytes, would you say that it is still 'safe' within its own scope?

Comment: See the alternative `main()` in the answer...the answer's yes, provided you're careful enough.

Comment: Thank you and everyone else so far for the answers. I expected nothing less from this incredible site of users. Can you please go further into explaining "provided, you're careful enough".  My understanding from your example code is that you can have any n length string passed as long as i deallocate the memory somehow.  thank you for your patience

Comment: The main reason for commenting on being careful is illustrated by saving the values in an array, and then using `free()` to release the allocated memory, thus avoiding leaks.  Carelessly calling the allocating version of the function could leak memory, which is not a good idea.  In short programs like this it isn't critical, but in long-running programs, memory leaks can be devastating.

Answer (score 1):

First, returning a pointer to a local like that isn't safe.  The idiom is to receive a pointer to a large enough buffer as a parameter to the function and fill it with the result.

The garbage is probably because you're not null-terminating your result string.  Make sure you append `'\0'` at the end.

**EDIT:** This is one way you could write your function using idiomatic C.

```
//buffer must be >= string_length + 1
void reverse_string(char *input_string, char* buffer, size_t string_length)
{
    int i = string_length;
    int j = 0;

    while (i != 0)
    {
        buffer[j] = input_string[i-1];
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    buffer[j] = '\0'; //null-terminate the string

    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Then, you call it somewhat like:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 16

int main()
{
    char* foo = "foo";
    size_t length = strlen(foo);
    char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];

    if(length < MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        reverse_string(foo, buffer, length);

        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error, string to reverse is too long");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of printing inside the function, how would i return it back to main and print there?

Comment: buffer is passed from main and printed there, i'll post an example.